# Grunt Server: Not supporting CORS, gives error

Tags: angularjs, cors, gruntjs

I have a server setup and everything was going fine but I am getting errors about

```
   ....  is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin
```

This is very strange as both the grunt server that hosts my Angular.js site is on port 9000 and my rest service is on port 8678.

Anyway I found this

```
  https://gist.github.com/Vp3n/5340891
```

which explains how to enable CORS on the grunt server but my grunt file doesn't look the same... this is my current part of my grunt file

```
  connect: {
      options: {
        port: 9000,
        // Change this to '0.0.0.0' to access the server from outside.
        hostname: 'localhost'
      },
      livereload: {
        options: {
          middleware: function (connect) {
            return [
              lrSnippet,
              mountFolder(connect, '.tmp'),
              mountFolder(connect, yeomanConfig.app)
            ];
          }
        }
      },
      test: {
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "my grunt file doesn't look the same", but you need to read the documentation of grunt-contrib-connect documentation which tells you that the `middleware` option accepts a function which should return an array of middlewares.

The referred gist is a simple middleware which allows CORS.

In your case it would look like:

```
connect: {
  options: {
    port: 9000,
    // Change this to '0.0.0.0' to access the server from outside.
    hostname: 'localhost'
  },
  livereload: {
    options: {
      middleware: function (connect) {
        return [
          lrSnippet,
          mountFolder(connect, '.tmp'),
          mountFolder(connect, yeomanConfig.app),
          function(req, res, next) {
            res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
            res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', '*');
            next();
          }
        ];
      }
    }
  },
  test: {
```

Comment: I'm having the same problem but this does not solve it? Could you take a look? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19391711/acces-control-allow-origin-with-grunt-server-and-flask-socketio-app?lq=1

Comment: How is the lrSnippet parameter defined? Can you provide the entire gruntfile?

Comment: @paweloque it's a old notation for grunt-connect, it's changed for grunt-contrib-connect

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same problem and cannot make the Grunt to behave correctly. Here is the corresponding fragment from Gruntfile.js:

```
connect: {
  options: {
    port: 9000,
    // Change this to '0.0.0.0' to access the server from outside.
    hostname: '0.0.0.0',
    livereload: 35729
  },
  livereload: {
    options: {
      open: true,
      base: [
        '.tmp',
        '<%= yeoman.app %>'
      ]
    }
  },
```

What would be the right way to updated it with middleware to set `Access-Control-Allow-...` Headers to `*`?

Comment: I have having the same problem, were you able to fix it.

Comment: I'm not sure if it will help you, but I had the same problem and it appeared that it was not grunt with the front-end app that was causing the CORS problem. It was the backend (API written in python/django) that was not allowing CORS. So the solution for me was to enable CORS for the backend. No changes for grunt were needed.

Comment: Yeah, I worked out, it wasn't grunt. I had to configure $http requests to allow JSONP.